# Theano The number of values on the `then` branch should have the same number of variables as the `else` branch

Tags: conditional-statements, theano

The title is the error message when I use ifelse in theano.

Say, I have a python snippet like this that I want to wirte in theano:

```
if condition:
  calculate(a,b,c)
else:
  # Do nothing
```

Now if I write in theano:

```
ifelse(condition, calculate(a,b,c), [])
```

if gave the error in the title. How to remedy this error, please ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`ifelse` needs to evaluate each branch of the condition at compile, your error is because the list you return on the false condition contains zero theano variables but the `calculate()` function returns at least one. I believe there are other checks on the datatype returned, but can't remember off the top of my head.  For the code you posted, if `calculate` always returns a scaler value:

`rval = ifelse(condition, calculate(a,b,c), 0.)`

should compile